# Back link not showing

Tags: seo, google-index

For this website http://www.it.uu.se/workshop/infinity2010/, there is a link from here http://atva10.comp.nus.edu.sg/assocEvents.html but when searching in Google.

```
link:http://www.it.uu.se/workshop/infinity2010/
```

It does not show up that page, what's the problem? (The link has been there at least 2 years)

Comment: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:4_V2dwbaeu4J:atva10.comp.nus.edu.sg/assocEvents.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk cached and found by Google. If you want better backlink searches then these cost sadly.

Answer (score 2):

Google only shows a very small sample of back links, it doesn't matter how long the links has existed, they will only show a few links. You may find more links from Bing Webmaster Center

Comment: But seems like Bing Webmaster Center can only find page owned by us? Is there other prominent SEO tools that can aid in search for back links?

Comment: No they provide a bigger sample of back links than Google does but again it's only a sample.

Comment: http://www.majesticseo.com/ is a good one, free if you own the site with limitations unless you go premium. Checking and reporting backlinks cost a lot cpu/ram/bandwidth hence why your need to pay if you want the most accurate reports.

Comment: @Anagio I can't seem to find where to search it, possible give me an url after searching the link to http://www.it.uu.se/workshop/infinity2010/?

Comment: @william007 you should try searching Bing Support

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to debug you troubles

1.make sure that the link tag is not using the `rel="nofollow"` this will automatically    cause your backlinks not to be shown,indexed

2.Make sure that the other site has not disvowed your backlinks

3.Use the following tool to test your backlinks [Open Site Explorer](http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/)